# Creating multiple dataframes (2) based off value in one column and stop when another value is observed

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, subset

A dataframe structure looks like so:

```
Date   Amount1     Amount2     Amount3

NaN     Port        NaN        thing1
1/1/17     2         3           3
2/1/17     2         3           3  
2/1/17     2         3           3  
4/1/17     2         3           3  
5/1/17     2         3           3  
6/1/17     2         3           3  
7/1/17     2         3           3  
8/1/17     2         3           3 
9/1/17     2         3           3
10/1/17    2         3           3
11/1/17    2         3           3 
12/1/17    2         3           3      
NaN     Port        NaN        thing2
1/1/17     2         3           3
2/1/17     2         3           3  
2/1/17     2         3           3  
4/1/17     2         3           3  
5/1/17     2         3           3  
6/1/17     2         3           3  
7/1/17     2         3           3  
8/1/17     2         3           3 
9/1/17     2         3           3
10/1/17    2         3           3
11/1/17    2         3           3 
12/1/17    2         3           3  
Total     Nan        NaN        NaN
1/1/17     2         3           3
2/1/17     2         3           3  
2/1/17     2         3           3  
4/1/17     2         3           3  
5/1/17     2         3           3  
6/1/17     2         3           3  
7/1/17     2         3           3  
8/1/17     2         3           3 
9/1/17     2         3           3
10/1/17    2         3           3
11/1/17    2         3           3 
12/1/17    2         3           3  
NaN        Nan       Nan         Nan
```

I am interested in creating 2 dataframes.

1.One dataframe collects the rows after thing2 is observed in the amount3 column and stops the row before total is observed in the date column.

2.The 2nd dataframe will start on the row after total is observed and stop when a NaN (null) value is observed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `idxmax` and `.iloc`

```
df1=df.loc[df.Amount3.eq('thing2').idxmax():df.Date.eq('Total').idxmax()-1].copy()
df2=df.loc[df.Date.eq('Total').idxmax():]
df2=df2.loc[:df2.Date.isnull().idxmax()-1]
```